# Why won't my widgets show up on my toplevel

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

I'm making a text editor program in python and I want a preferences window to appear when you press Edit > Preferences, the window appears, but the widgets I added don't.

```py
def OpenPrefs():
        pref_window = Toplevel()
        pref_window.title("TextWrite - Preferences")
        pref_window.geometry("400x225")

        # Options

        menuframe = Frame(pref_window, width = 400, height = 225)
        menuframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        global theme_btn
        global theme_menu

        theme_btn = Menubutton(menuframe, width = 10, height = 0.1, text = "Theme")
        theme_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        theme_menu = Menu(theme_btn, tearoff = 0)
        theme_btn.config(menu = theme_menu)

        theme_menu.add_command(label = "Light")
        theme_menu.add_command(label = "Dark")
```

Comment: When I try to run this I get an error saying that the `height` of the `Menubutton` must be an integer. What happens if you try setting the height to `1`?

Comment: @JRiggles that actually fixes it, thanks! Weird I didn't get the error though.